# The argument type 'Future<Image?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image' in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to resize an image. But I get the following error in `img.copyResize(image, width: 120)`

> The argument type 'Future<Image?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

  Future resizeImage() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      var image = img.decodeImageFile(pickedImage.path);
      var thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, width: 120);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decodeImageFile(String path, {int? frame})` function of package [image: ^4.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/image) is future that returns nullable `Image`. Await it then null check.

**Solution**

```dart
if (pickedImage != null) {
    var image = await img.decodeImageFile(pickedImage.path);
    if (image != null) {
      var thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, width: 120);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing it's probably because your variable "image" can be null... To fix this, if you are 100% sure this variable will have always some data, you can do the following:

```
var image = img.decodeImageFile(pickedImage!.path); // Adding "!"
var thumbnail = img.copyResize(image!, width: 120); // Adding "!"
```

Although I'm not sure because there's not that much information given

Comment: This doesn't work